# System Extension Validation Fails

Tags: macos, networkextension, macos-system-extension

im trying to submit a Network Extension activation request but i get this error.

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSSystemExtensionErrorDomain error 9.)
```

I looked it up and apparently it means "validationFailed". Is there a way to debug this because i cant seem to figure out why the validation is failing. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the solution. You need to set the NEMachServiceName property on the Info.plist of the extension to match the app group name.